# How to get image path while uploading image

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a requirement to upload an image and following is the HTML code

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload" align="center">
                <div data-bind="if: doctor.imgSrc"> 
                    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"><img data-bind="attr: { src: doctor.imgSrc }"/></div>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="ifnot: doctor.imgSrc">

                    <div data-bind="if: doctor.imagePath">
                    <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"><img data-bind="attr: { src: doctor.imagePath }"/></div>
                </div>
                <div data-bind="ifnot: doctor.imagePath">
                <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/ui_resources/img/profile_pic.png" /></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
                <div>
                <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" data-bind=" file: doctor.imgFile, fileObjectURL: doctor.imgSrc"/></span>
                <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and following is the JS codes

```
var Doctor = (function () {
    function Doctor(data) {
        this.id = ko.observable('');
        this.name = ko.observable('');
        this.degree = ko.observable('');
        this.gender = ko.observable('');
        this.username = ko.observable('');
        this.password = ko.observable('');
        this.email = ko.observable('');
        this.mobile = ko.observable('');
        this.imgFile = ko.observable('');
        this.imgSrc = ko.observable('');
        this.imagePath = ko.observable('');
        this.userid = ko.observable('');
        this.department = ko.observable('');
        this.schedules = ko.observableArray([]);
        if (data != null) {
            this.id = ko.observable(data['id']);
            this.name = ko.observable(data['name']);
            this.degree = ko.observable(data['degree']);
            this.gender = ko.observable(data['gender']);
            this.username = ko.observable(data['username']);
            this.password = ko.observable(data['password']);
            this.email = ko.observable(data['email']);
            this.mobile = ko.observable(data['mobile']);
            this.imgFile = ko.observable(data['imgFile']);
            this.imgSrc = ko.observable(data['imagePath']);
            this.imagePath = ko.observable(data['imagePath']);
            this.userid = ko.observable(data['userid']);
            this.department = ko.observable(data['department']);
        }
    }
    return Doctor;
})();

var doc = new Doctor(doctor); 
function vm() { 
var self = this; 
self.doctor = doc;
}
var viewModel = new vm(); 
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Now I have a save button and when its clicked it calls the following function

```
$('#saveButton').click(function(){ 
alert('savebutton'); 
var testjson=ko.toJSON(viewModel.doctor); 
console.log(testjson);
});
```

The problem with it is I am not getting the imagepath,imgsrc and imgfile in the json.

This is the json

```
{"id":2,"name":"doc2","degree":"DA(Anaesthesia)","gender":"Female","username":"doc","password":"doc","email":"doc1@doc1.com","mobile":"12345678901","imgSrc":"imagePathValue","imagePath":"imagePathValue","userid":11,"department":"Bio-Chemistry","schedules":[{"id":"0","day":"Monday","fromtime":"17:21","totime":"18:21","hospitalId":5,"hospital":"Yashoda"},{"id":"1","day":"Tuesday","fromtime":"05:23","totime":"12:18","hospitalId":5,"hospital":"Yashoda"},{"id":"2","day":"Wednesday","fromtime":"11:23","totime":"12:23","hospitalId":5,"hospital":"Yashoda"},{"id":"3","day":"Thursday","fromtime":"17:27","totime":"18:27","hospitalId":46,"hospital":"Sai Bhavani"},{"id":"4","day":"Friday","fromtime":"10:30","totime":"12:30","hospitalId":46,"hospital":"Sai Bhavani"}]}
```

Can anybody please point out the mistake I am doing?

**Update**

Following is the custom binding for file

```
var windowURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

ko.bindingHandlers.file = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).change(function() {
            var file = this.files[0];
            if (ko.isObservable(valueAccessor())) {
                valueAccessor()(file);
                formdata.append("image",file);
            }
        });
    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var file = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var bindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        if (bindings.fileObjectURL && ko.isObservable(bindings.fileObjectURL)) {
            var oldUrl = bindings.fileObjectURL();
            if (oldUrl) {
                windowURL.revokeObjectURL(oldUrl);
            }
            bindings.fileObjectURL(file && windowURL.createObjectURL(file));
        }

        if (bindings.fileBinaryData && ko.isObservable(bindings.fileBinaryData)) {
            if (!file) {
                bindings.fileBinaryData(null);
            } else {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    bindings.fileBinaryData(e.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of posting your `Doctor` view-model with all its completely irrelevant properties please post the code of your `file` and `fileObjectURL` custom bindings!

Comment: @nemesv Please see now and if you need more codes then please tell me

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `data` parameter you're using to initialize the `Doctor` does not contain an `imgFile` property.  Therefore, you're creating an observable on `undefined` -- and that won't show up in JSON.

Change the `imgFile` assignment to:

```
this.imgFile = ko.observable(data['imgFile'] || '');
```

Also, `imgSrc` and `imgPath` **both** grab their data from `data['imagePath']` -- is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: Thanks for the answer,+1.The problem is with formdata.I have used 2 formdata1 and formdata.In formdata1 I am apending the image and in formdata I am adding the form details and submitting the formdata.As it does not have image appended so the json was like that.But thanks for the answser so upvoted

Comment: Your custom binding handler does not reference either imagePath or imgSrc so I don't think it has anything to do with your issue.  By setting imagePath (or imgSrc) to 'undefined', it will not appear in JSON.  If you fix that, your JSON will appear as you requested.